# Converting CSV to HTML keeping format

Tags: python, html, pandas

My objective is: Converting `DF` to `HTML` which is send as an everyday mail

Current Method : converting df to `csv` to `html`

Problem: I have created my df which has `as_index=True` set, but when I save it to a csv this formatting is lost :

***Example DataFrame:***

[image: MY DF]

Now when I save this df using `to_csv()`, the formatting in the index is lost ( means that ABC is now written 3 times across the index, instead of once as I want it)

**I want the CSV to have the same formatting is that possible?**

Comment: Why not use the [`.to_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) method?

Answer (score 0):

Please install `pandas` and use `to_html()`.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

Hope it can help you.